# Scheduled jobs using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

I have several AWS lambda functions triggered by events from other applications, e.g. via Kinesis. Some of this events should trigger something happening at another time. As an example, consider the case of sending a reminder/notification e-mail to a user about something when 24 hours have passed since event X happened.

I have previously worked with lambda functions that schedule other lambda functions by dynamically creating CloudWatch "cron" rules in runtime, but I'm now revisiting my old design and considering whether this is the best approach. It was a bit tedious to set up lambdas that schedule other lambdas, because in addition to submitting CW rules with the new lambda as the target I also had to deal with runtime granting of the invoked lambda permissions to be triggered by the new CW rule.

So another approach I'm considering is to submit jobs to be done by adding them to a database table, with a given execution time, and then have one single CW cron rule running every x minutes that checks the database for due jobs. This reduces complexity of the CW rules (only one, static rule needed), lambda permissions (also static) etc, but adds complexity in an additional database table etc. Another difference is that while the old design only performed one executed one "job" per invocation, this design would potentially execute 100 pending jobs in the same invocation, and I'm not sure if this could cause timeout issues etc.

Did anyone successfully implement something similar? What approach did you choose?
I know there are also other services such as AWS Batch, but this seems overkill for scheduling of simple tasks such as sending an e-mail when time `t` has passed since event `e` happened, since to my knowledge it doesn't support simple lambda jobs. SQS also supports timed messages, but only up to 15 minutes, so it doesn't seem useful for scheduling something in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting alternative is to use **AWS Step Functions** to trigger the AWS Lambda function after a given delay.

Step Functions has a Wait state that can schedule or delay execution, so you can can implement a fairly simple Step Functions state machine that puts a delay in front of calling a Lambda function. No database required!

For an example of the concept (slightly different, but close enough), see:

- [Using AWS Step Functions To Schedule Or Delay SNS Message Publication - Alestic.com](https://alestic.com/2019/05/aws-delayed-sns-step-functions/?utm_campaign=website&utm_source=Last%20Week%20in%20AWS&utm_medium=email)
- [Task Timer - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html)